# Coil ImageView doesn't fit exactly

Tags: android, coil

According to `Coil`s docs, I don't have to make any configuration for my image to `fit()`. The problem is, that the `ImageView` is not loading correctly:

This is my configuration for the `ImageView` with `Picasso`:

```
picasso.load(unsplashResult?.photoUrls?.thumbnailUrl)
                        .fit()
                        .error(R.drawable.img_placeholder)
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.img_placeholder)
                        .into(currentImageView)
```

And this is the code with `Coil`:

```
currentImageView.load(unsplashResult?.photoUrls?.thumbnailUrl) {
                        placeholder(R.drawable.img_placeholder)
                        error(R.drawable.img_placeholder)
                    }
```

The result on my `ImageView` is not the same though.

This is how `Coil` loads them:

[image]

And this is how `Picasso` loads them:

[image]

Question is, how can I achieve the same result with `Coil`?

**EDIT**

This is my `ImageView`:

```
<ImageView
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:id="@+id/ivUnsplashImage"
            android:src="@drawable/some_unsplash_img"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: hmmm. actually it says that there is no need to make any fit configurations. https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/migrating/

Comment: on Coils README in github

Comment: Were you been able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 7):

**Based on this document**

You can work around this by setting the scaleType to centerCrop or scale(Scale.FILL) on your request.

> https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/api/coil-base/coil.request/-request-builder/scale/
>
> https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/api/coil-base/coil.size/-scale/

you are set `Scale` type this way

```
view.load(chatMessageBean.thumb) {
       crossfade(750)
       placeholder(errorPlaceHolder)
       transformations(CircleCropTransformation())
       error(errorPlaceHolder)
       scale(Scale.FILL)
}
```

Comment: just one thing, this behavior does resolve, but on second load it still persists

Comment: @coroutineDispatcher Can you elaborate more in details?

Comment: well this piece of code does work, but if I click the same fragment again, the photos will get back to the previous state (the not correct one, picture 1 in the question)

Answer (score 2):

So, according to migration guide answer should be like;

```
imageView.scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER
```

or it should be defined in XML

```
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

Comment: Nope, same result

Comment: did you check this? https://github.com/coil-kt/coil/issues/20 i think there is an issue with scaling

Comment: @coroutineDispatcher Looks like this is related to this issue (https://github.com/coil-kt/coil/issues/20). I'm working on fixing it for the 0.7.0 release in a couple days.

Comment: yes, but in my case it still doesn't give the expected result, even after setting the `scaletype` to `centercrop`

Answer (score 2):

As much I understood from the documentation you should use ImageView.ScaleType

```
imageView.scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY
```

or you can use it into your xml tag of your ImageView

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Apart from FIT_XY you can use `ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP` too according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the line `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` in your layout XML file.